# count total products from users galleries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

im trying to create a query that counts the total products from a user, but my code isnt working, i leave above my code:

Tables:
Galleries:

```
 - id;
 - title

Products
- id;
- gallery_id;
- title;
- price
```

Models:
Gallery

```
 public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

My query:

```
$totalProducts = Gallery::where('user_id', $userId)->products()->count();
```

Error:

```
Non-static method App\Gallery::products() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count products of one gallery, you need to get the object:

```
$totalProducts = Gallery::where('user_id', $userId)->first()->products()->count();
```

If you want to count all products of a user, you should add [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation first:

```
public function userProducts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Gallery');
}
```

Then count products:

```
User::find($id)->userProducts()->count();
```

Comment: But in your example im not getting the total products that i have, im only getting one of many i have, i guess your getting the first record.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pastview = DB::table('tbl_field_data')
       ->where('id',$pid)
       ->select('tbl_field_data.*', 'tbl_field_data.view')
       ->first();
```

DB::table('tbl_field_data')->where('id', $pid)->update(['view' => $pastview->view+1 ]);